# Redirect port 80 Request To Different Apps Based On Path

Tags: nginx

I need to install a uWSGI app and Kibana4 / elastic search stack on the same server.  The uwsgi app only needs to be used when a user accesses the server via [server_IP]/charts/ and I'd like Kibana4 to be accessed via [Server_IP].

Both listen on port 80 via their own separate conf files and, predictably, the uwsgi app doesn't allow for Kibana4 to receive requests.

How would I adjust my conf files to allow the access I need? I'm a bit confused as to what I need to use (rewrite, redirect, something else?)

Thanks for your time

nginx_conf_for_uwsgi:

```
server {
    server_name           192.168.250.37;
    listen                80;
    root                  /usr/local/wsgi;
    access_log            /var/log/nginx/graph_server/access.log;
    error_log             /var/log/nginx/graph_server/error.log;
    client_max_body_size  500M;
    proxy_read_timeout    600;

location / {
    include             uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass          192.168.250.37:9091;
    uwsgi_read_timeout  600;
    }
}
```

kibana4.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name 192.168.250.37;

    #auth_basic "Restricted Access";
    #auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd.users;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.250.37:5601;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

nginx.conf:

```
user              nginx;
worker_processes  4;
error_log         /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid               /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    index         index.html index.htm;

    # Increase header buffer size (needed for PHP)
    proxy_buffer_size        128k;
    proxy_buffers            4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size  256k;

    # Update the logs to display the real IP address after removing the IP for
    # the load balancers
    set_real_ip_from   redacted;  # a
    set_real_ip_from   redacted;  # b
    real_ip_header     X-Forwarded-For;
    real_ip_recursive  on;

    # Custom logger to display the subdomain folder (if applicable)
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    log_format  log_thing '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                               '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                               '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" '
                               '"$http_x_forwarded_for" sub:"$subdomain"';
    log_format  i_server  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                               '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                               'filename:"$http_filename"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile           on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        server_name  localhost;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }

        error_page  404              /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to use nginx as a reverse proxy which is effectively what you are doing already. This way you have one nginx virtual host listening on port 80 which forwards different locations to separate nginx vhosts listening on different ports on your system.

You nginx reverse proxy vhost would look something like this, the 3 proxy_set_header lines can be moved to the server block if all locations work with them

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name 192.168.250.37;
port_in_redirect off

location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }

location /charts {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
}
```

Then change you Kibanaconf to listen on port 8081 and uwsgi to listen on 8082

Alternatively you can combine the two vhosts into one and will need to set custom aliases for the root folders under each location and rearrange.

```
server {
listen 80;

server_name 192.168.250.37;
root  /usr/local/wsgi;
client_max_body_size  500M;
proxy_read_timeout    600;
#auth_basic "Restricted Access";
#auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd.users;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.250.37:5601;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

location /charts {
    include             uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass          192.168.250.37:9091;
    uwsgi_read_timeout  600;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's for the help - I appreciate it.